Vanishing virtual work done by non-holonomic constraints
I was reading classical mechanics by NC Rana. I was reading a topic on vanishing virtual work done due to constraint forces. How do you prove that the virtual work done by non-holonomic constraint which are homogeneous functions of velocities is zero?  There is a proof given in the text but i find it unclear. How did he proceed after eq 1.31. It says the first summand will cancel with $J(r , t)$. How?



Ref. 1 is effectively considering $m$ independent non-holonomic constraints of the form$^1$
$$ f_{\ell}(q,\dot{q},t)~\equiv~\underbrace{g_{\ell}(q,\dot{q},t)}_{=\frac{1}{n}\dot{q}^j\frac{\partial g_{\ell}(q,\dot{q},t)}{\partial \dot{q}^j}}+J_{\ell}(q,t)~=~0, \qquad  \ell~\in\{1,\dots,m\}, $$
which equivalently can be written as $m$ independent non-holonomic one-form constraints of the form
$$ \omega_{\ell}~\equiv~\frac{1}{n}\frac{\partial g_{\ell}(q,\dot{q},t)}{\partial \dot{q}^j}\mathrm{d}q^j+ J_{\ell}(q,t)\mathrm{d}t~=~0, \qquad  \ell~\in\{1,\dots,m\}.$$
For an infinitesimal virtual displacement with frozen time $\delta t=0$, they satisfy
$$ \frac{1}{n}\frac{\partial g_{\ell}(q,\dot{q},t)}{\partial \dot{q}^j}\delta q^j~=~0, \qquad  \ell~\in\{1,\dots,m\}.\tag{1.31}$$
One can therefore add such terms (times Lagrange multipliers) to d'Alembert's principle (DAP) and Lagrange equations (LE), cf. e.g. eq. (2.74) and my Phys.SE answer here.
References:

N.C. Rana & P.S. Joag, Classical Mechanics, 1991; p. 47 + 85.

--
$^1$ Here we assume that the functions $g_{\ell}(q,\dot{q},t)$ are homogeneous of order $n>0$ in the generalized velocities, cf. eq. (1.29).

Can you pls explain the first line? how did you simplify gℓ(q,q˙,t) ?

I updated the answer.
